# Sourcetree not able to access GitLab

Tags: ssh, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I have 2 PCs, each with SourceTree installed. On each machine, I run `ssh-keygen -t rsa` to generate the public & private keys and I place them in the folders:

```
G:/.ssh/PC1

G:/.ssh/PC2
```

under each folder, there are 3 files : `id_rsa`, `id_rsa.pub`, `known_hosts`.

I copied the content of each `id_ras.pub` to create a SSH key in server. On each machine, in SourceTree, I specify the "SSH Client Configuration" so that

`SSH Key` points to `G:\.ssh\PC1\id_rsa` & `G:\.ssh\PC2\id_rsa`

OpenSSH is used in both machine for SSH Client.

But it appears that one of the PCs is able to access GitLab properly in SourceTree, i.e., push/pull work; on the other PC, when launching SourceTree, it alerts:

> 'ssh-agent' failed with code -1: System.Exception:Unable to start 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\bin\ssh-agent.exe' check the git installation.

Further, I tried a new check out from GitLab to a new folder on the PC that is not working and after that it starts to work. But later, it stops working and gives the same alert.

I tried to pull from repository, and it errors:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\bin\sh.exe: *** fork: can't reserve 
memory for stack 0x2E60000 - 0x3060000, Win32 error 0

  0 [main] sh 11020 sync_with_child: child 7124(0x238) died before initialization with status code 0x1
 13 [main] sh 11020 sync_with_child: *** child state waiting for longjmp
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Atlassian\SourceTree\tools\openssh_wrapper.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable

 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```